# PHP scandir except subdirecrories

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with script when I scan a folder because array contains sub directories as well:

```
$location = 'c:\test';
 $files = scandir($location , 1);
```

but i would like to scan only files but not folders

Comment: if after the provided code you iterate over the files with a foreach loop, you can check if its a directory `if(!is_dir($file)){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. It filters out all directories.

```
$result = array_filter(scandir('/path/to/dir'), function($item) {
    return !is_dir('/path/to/dir/' . $item);
});
```

Comment: Do `use ($location)` maybe ;)